# Как удалить одинаковые по названию файлы но с разными расширениями?

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система

Как я могу удалить все файлы из папки с одинаковыми названиями, но с разными расширениями?

```
foobar.bmp
foobar.exe
foobar.jpg
foobar.mp3
foobar.png
foobar.txt
foobar.wri
```

Могу ли я указать что-то на подобии `os.remove(foobar.**)`, чтобы удалить все это? Извините за глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться модулем `glob` и его одноимённым методом для поиска файлов и директорий по некоторой маске.

***Примеры:***

```py
import glob
import os


for file in glob.glob('foobar.*'):
    os.remove(file)
```

```py
import glob
import shutil


for directory in glob.glob('*/'):
    shutil.rmtree(directory)
```

Comment: Спасибо, можете также подсказать каким образом я могу удалить абсолютно все папки из директории?

Comment: @blox Рад помочь :) Насчёт удаления директорий, я дополнил ответ.